# Python3 error handling loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
def errorCheck(daySales):
  while True:
    try:
        daySales = float(daySales)

    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter a number - for example: 7')
        print('Try again!')
    except Exception as err:
        print('Unknown error - please contact the programmer!')
        print(type(err))

    return(float(daySales))    

counter=0
day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday',
       'Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
daySales=()
sales=[]
totalsales=[]

for i in range(len(day)):
    print('Enter sales for ' + day[i] + ': ', end="")
    daySales = input()
    errorCheck(daySales)
    sales = sales + [float(daySales)]

for i in range(len(day)):
    print('\nYour sales for ' + day[i] + ' were: $', sales[i], end="")

print('\nWhich equates to a weekly sales total of: $' ,end="")
sumOfList = sum(sales)
print(sumOfList)
```

This script does exactly what I want it to do IF the user enters numbers, however if an exception happens, it catches it but continues on to the next step.  For example, if I enter "foobar" for the sales for Monday, the script tells me to only enter a number, but then goes to the next input, which is Tuesday.
How can I make my loop stay on the 'day' until the user enters a valid number?

Comment: You have a `while` loop, but regardless of input/exceptions, you are doing `return`.  You only want to `return` if there is no exception.  You also want to be getting the `input()` in the loop.  Otherwise, how would the user be able to enter in another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer is to wrap the input/check sequence in a while loop:

```
unchecked = True
while unchecked:
    daySales = input()
    errorCheck(daySales)
```

Notice that the way your code is currently structured, the return `float(daySales)` in `errorCheck` will ensure that an exception will be raised.

Now let's address some other very strange things you have in your code. Reading from the top:

1. There is a while loop in `errorCheck`. It never runs more than once because it contains a `return`.
2. The return in `errorCheck` will trigger any exception that was previously caught and reported. This can be replaced by a None return in case of exception. The loop shown above can rely on this check.
3. `counter` is never used. Neither is `totalSales`.
4. `input` accepts the stuff you are trying to `print` as an argument.
5. `for i in range(len(day)):` can be replaced by `for d in day:`. This means that `day[i]` becomes `d` in the loop.
6. The second loop of the same form can be turned into `for d, s in zip(day, sales):`.
7. Strings are better constructed via formatting rather than adding with `+`.

Here is what the cleaned up code would look like:

```
def errorCheck(daySales):
    try:
        return float(daySales)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter a number - for example: 7')
        print('Try again!')
    except Exception as err:
        print('Unknown error - please contact the programmer!')
        print(type(err))
    return None

day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday',
       'Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
sales=[]

for d in day:
    daySales = None
    while daySales is None:
        daySales = input('Enter sales for {}:'.format(d))
        daySales = errorCheck(daySales)
    sales.append(daySales)

for d, s in zip(day, sales):
    print('\nYour sales for {} were: ${}'.format(d, s))

sumOfList = sum(sales)
print('\nWhich equates to a weekly sales total of: ${}'.format(sumOfList))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped out a lot.  counter and totalSales were left over from something else I was trying to do.  I am just starting to learn Python, so some of the things you used we haven't covered yet, but I get the point about putting the error checking inside a while loop inside the for loop.

Comment: Playing around with this, this makes so much more sense than the way I was trying to do it., especially using 'for d in day' instead of 'for i in range...'  Had to look up the zip() function, which is also a pretty cool function!

Answer (score -1):

Put your `return(float(daySales))` in an else statement.  So it only runs if `try` was successful.

Comment: True statement, but comes nowhere near answering op's question. This should be a comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't have the reputation at the time to post it as a comment, sorry about that.